# call a function by using drupal add js

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

i'm debugging a drupal module, the second line drupal_add_js call a js function in uc_discounts.js

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'uc_discounts') . '/uc_discounts.js');
drupal_add_js('(function($){jQuery(document).ready(function () { uc_discountsOnLoad(e); })})(jQuery);', array('type' => 'inline', 'group' => JS_DEFAULT, 'scope' => 'footer'));
```

there is an error message in firebug, ReferenceError: uc_discountsOnLoad is not defined, anyone can figure out the problems?

** update **

i knew the problems!

the uc_discountsOnLoad if defined outside (function ($) {})(jQuery); can be called~ but it can't use jquery symbol, it is a conflict!
but in the situation , how do i call this function?

```
function uc_discountsOnLoad(e) {

  context = $('body');
  uc_discountsProcessCodes(context, e);

  //Add click event listener to discounts pane button once
  $("input[id*=uc-discounts-button]:not(.uc_discountsOnLoad-processed)", 
    context).addClass("uc_discountsOnLoad-processed").click(function(e) {
      uc_discountsProcessCodes(context, e);
      //Return false to prevent default actions and propogation
      return false;
    });
}
```

if define the uc_discountsOnLoad(e) outside the (function ($) {})(jQuery);, $('body') will got an error!

Answer (score 0):

The `uc_discountsOnLoad(e)` function cannot be found.

- Check `uc_discounts.js` to see if the function actually exists.
- `uc_discounts.js` gets loaded after the function is called? (Check your page source)

Comment: 100% sure functions exists and uc_discounts.js is loaded~